# Overstaying in South Africa

Tags: us-citizens, overstaying, south-africa

I am a US citizen, South African born. I went in July to spend time with my mom who was sickly. I came back to the States beginning of Aug only to turn back around 2 weeks later as my mom was hospitalized and upon landing back in South Africa, she passed away. As per our religious custom, we were unable to do anything for a month. After that period, I started working on my moms estate and only went back to the US middle of Oct. Just last week, beginning of a new year, I had to go back to finalize everything and was told I am not allowed to enter because I overstayed on my last visit. I explained to Home Affairs at the airport the reason, and they made their mind up sending me back to the States. It's ridiculous that they would not even let me prove myself and I understand they probably hear this BS all the time. I even told them I will show my moms death certificate but they weren't listening to me. Upon arriving back, I immediately set out to appeal this. So my question is, how long does an appeal take to process and is there anything else I can do so I can go back to SA?

Comment: Were you actually given a ban or were you refused visa-free entry? If the latter, you could apply for a visa which would hopefully be approved given your citizenship and the circumstances of your overstay

Comment: Were you never a citizen of South Africa?

Comment: Did you really overstay on your last visit? US citizens are usually entitled to 90 days of stay per visit and the dates you are mentioning contradict that you stayed longer than 90 days.

Comment: @ Michael--I was born a South African, lived there for 24years then got married and moved to the States. @ Tor-Einar-- like I said I was there from July 1 to Aug 3 then reentered Aug 20 when my mom was hospitalized. I stayed from Aug 20 to Oct 14

Comment: My 90 days included the time I came back to the States for the 2 week before going back.

Comment: Have you tried applying for your South African passport? When you acquired your US nationality, did you apply to retain your South African nationality? Since you were born a South African citizen, you are always entitled to permanent residence in South Africa. You might need a visa to return to take up this right - but I don't see how they can deny it. (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/South_African_nationality_law)

Comment: User has not returned to clarify. Putting on hold for now.